# Problems with connection GeoServer - AJAX in web map code

Tags: geoserver, wfs, ajax

I'm trying to create a WFS connection to show a layer in a Leaflet map, but the layer isn't uploading. I supposedly have correctly employed the code (I've been testing the code with another GeoServer URL that is hosted in the internet and I was able to see that WFS layer). So supposedly the problem is from the connection with localhost, but I don't know how to fix it.

I've checked the layer is published in GeoServer. I can see the JSON file from the URL, and I can upload the layer from a WFS connection in QGIS. So I really don't know what is happening there. By elimination I think it's a problem with GeoServer, but I have been able to visualize in my Leaflet map the two layers I have uploaded from GeoServer using WMS service.

In var owsrootUrl I've tested both 'geoserver/andalucia/ows' and 'geoserver/ows', and neither of them work.

The URL of the service in my PC is http://localhost:8080/geoserver/andalucia/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=andalucia%3Aestaciones&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

I'm using jQuery 3.5.1. The code I used for the WFS connection is:

```
        var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/andalucia/ows';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'andalucia:estaciones',
            outputFormat: 'application/json',
        };
        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
        var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                var estaciones = new L.geoJson(data, {
                    style: {"color":"green","weight":2},
                    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                        layer.bindPopup("Has hecho click en ");
                    }}
                ).addTo(map);
                }
            });
```

The entire code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>La Alta Velocidad en Andalucía y el desmantelamiento de la red de Media Distancia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" ></script>
        <style>
            body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }
            html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
                    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
            }
            .info {
                padding: 6px 8px;
                font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
                background: white;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
                box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            .info h2 {
                margin: 0 0 5px;
                color: #777;
            }
            .legend {
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>
        <button onclick=fullScreenView()>Ver en vista completa</button>
        <script>
            var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
                +'contributors',
            maxZoom: 18
            });
            
            var darkLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
                subdomains: 'abcd',
                maxZoom: 20
            });
            
            var watermap = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
                attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                subdomains: 'abcd',
                minZoom: 1,
                maxZoom: 16,
                ext: 'jpg'
            });
            
            var provincias = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
                layers: 'andalucia:provincias',
                format: 'image/png',
                transparent: true,
                tiled: true,
                attribution: "Natural Earth"
            });
     
            var lineas = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
                layers: 'andalucia:lineas_tren',
                format: 'image/png',
                transparent: true,
                tiled: true,
                attribution: "Natural Earth"
            });
            
            var baseMaps = {
                "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
                "Fondo oscuro": darkLayer,
                "Terreno": watermap
            };
    
            var map = L.map('map', {
                center: [37.295, -4.568],
                zoom: 8,
                layers: [OSM, provincias, lineas],
                scrollWheelZoom: true
            });
            
        var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/andalucia/ows';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'andalucia:estaciones',
            outputFormat: 'application/json',
        };
        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
        var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                var estaciones = new L.geoJson(data, {
                    style: {"color":"green","weight":2},
                    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                        layer.bindPopup("Has hecho click en ");
                    }}
                ).addTo(map);
                }
            });
            
            var marker = L.marker([37.3922422036603, -5.975281017358207])
            .addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<h2> Estación de Sevilla Santa Justa </h2> <p> Es la principal estación ferroviaria de Sevilla. Fue inaugrada el 2 de mayo de 1991. Su apertura supuso la unión de los servicios de las históricas estaciones de Plaza de Armas (o estación de Córdoba) y de San Bernardo (o estación de Cádiz). Es la tercera estación de España, con un volumen de viajeros cercano a los 13 millones anuales de los cuales alrededor de 7 millones se corresponden con el tráfico de cercanías.  </p> <br><img src='images/santajusta.jpg'/>")

            var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
            legend.onAdd = function (map) {
                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
                    div.innerHTML +=
                    '<img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=andalucia:lineas_tren" alt="legend" width="350" height="300">';
                return div;
            };
            legend.addTo(map);
            
            var title = L.control();
            title.onAdd = function (map) {
                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                    div.innerHTML +=
                    '<h2>La situación del tren en Andalucía</h2>El desmantelamiento de la red de Media Distancia y el auge del AVE';
                return div;
            };
            title.addTo(map);
            
            var overlayMaps = {
                "Estaciones de tren": estaciones,
                "Líneas de tren": lineas,
                "Provincias": provincias
            };          
            
            L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed:false}).addTo(map);

            L.control.scale({
                position: 'bottomright',
                maxWidth: 400,
                imperial: false
            }).addTo(map);      
            
            var mapId = document.getElementById('map');
                function fullScreenView(){
                mapId.requestFullscreen();
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it works from Qgis then the problem is with your leaflet code. Please add the exact URL and post body and the response from geoserver to your question. If that is not clear then you should add the geoserver log

Comment: The exact url of the service is the one I posted before. I've updated the post with the entire html code. I don't think Leaflet is the problem: I was checking another web mad I had with a WFS service that isn't working anymore and I haven't touched that code. But I still can see the layer using the WFS connection to QGIS.

Comment: **Please add the exact URL and post body and the response from geoserver to your question. If that is not clear then you should add the geoserver log**

Comment: What actual WFS request is generated by Leaflet?